# D3: Unit Bar Chart with Brush and Zoom (transpose)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've attempted to transpose the Bar chart from block
https://bl.ocks.org/misanuk/fc39ecc400eed9a3300d807783ef7607 to get closer to what I would like for my own needs, but have become stuck on getting the Y axis to work the same as the original example.  The left Y axis should resize and move based on the zooming and brushing, but whatever I try it remains static.

Any guidance appreciated.  Here's the code (as long as you have d3.v4 loaded in the browser it should work without a server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

body {
  font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

circle {
  fill: #FF7700;
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
}

.axis {
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: #888;
  font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
}

.axis > path {
  stroke: #888;
}


</style>

<body>
</body>

<--script src="../src/d3.v4.min.js"></script-->
<script> 
var data = [
  {
    "message_id": 1970268,
    "sent_time": "2013-04-05",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 2298946,
    "sent_time": "2013-05-29",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 2575515,
    "sent_time": "2013-07-13",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 2610242,
    "sent_time": "2013-07-17",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 2926234,
    "sent_time": "2013-08-20",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3110458,
    "sent_time": "2013-09-06",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 2
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3130002,
    "sent_time": "2013-09-08",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 3
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3255637,
    "sent_time": "2013-09-18",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 4
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3387239,
    "sent_time": "2013-09-29",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3447200,
    "sent_time": "2013-10-03",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 7
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3861761,
    "sent_time": "2013-11-05",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 7
  },
  {
    "message_id": 3949012,
    "sent_time": "2013-11-12",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4082149,
    "sent_time": "2013-11-21",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4155079,
    "sent_time": "2013-11-27",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4214299,
    "sent_time": "2013-12-03",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 4
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4348242,
    "sent_time": "2013-12-12",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 3
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4374202,
    "sent_time": "2013-12-15",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 6
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4384330,
    "sent_time": "2013-12-16",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 3
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4495880,
    "sent_time": "2013-12-26",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4569256,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-01",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 3
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4583204,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-02",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4621515,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-04",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 7
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4678673,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-07",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 1
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4743194,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-10",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 4
  },
  {
    "message_id": 4761212,
    "sent_time": "2014-01-11",
    "messages_sent_in_day": 5
  }];
</script>
<script>

/* Adapted from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 */

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    margin2 = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 400},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    width2 = 500 - margin2.left - margin2.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([5, width-100]),
    x2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([5, width2]),
    y = d3.scaleTime().range([10, height]),
    y2 = d3.scaleTime().range([10, height])
    ;

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(1);
    yAxis2 = d3.axisLeft(y2).tickSize(0);

var brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width2, height]])
    .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

// Data Load from CSV

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sent_time = parseTime(d.sent_time);
  });

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.messages_sent_in_day; });
  var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.messages_sent_in_day; });
  var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.sent_time; });
  var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.sent_time; });

  x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
  y.domain([yMin, new Date()]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  var num_messages = function(dataArray, domainRange) { return d3.sum(dataArray, function(d) {
    return d.sent_time >= domainRange.domain()[0] && d.sent_time <= domainRange.domain()[1];
    })
  }

  // append scatter plot to main chart area
  var messages = focus.append("g");
    messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    messages.selectAll("message")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('class', 'message')
        .attr("r", 2)
        .style("opacity", 0.4)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.messages_sent_in_day); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sent_time); })

  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);

  // Summary Stats
  focus.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x",0 - height)
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left)/2) + " ," +
                             (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Messages");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

  // append scatter plot to brush chart area
   var messages = context.append("g");
       messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
       messages.selectAll("message")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr('class', 'messageContext')
          .attr("r",1)
          .style("opacity", .6)
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return x2(d.messages_sent_in_day); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return y2(d.sent_time); })

  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis y-axis")
        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
        .call(yAxis2);

  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, y.range());



//create brush function redraw scatterplot with selection
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || y2.range();
  y.domain(s.map(y2.invert, y2));
  focus.selectAll(".message")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.messages_sent_in_day); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sent_time); });
  focus.select(".y-axis").call(yAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(height / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  y.domain(t.rescaleY(y2).domain());
  focus.selectAll(".message")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.messages_sent_in_day); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sent_time); })
        ;
  focus.select(".y-axis").call(yAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, y.range().map(t.invertY, t));
}

</script>
```

Comment: jsFiddle might be useful here https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/hxb40g0e/

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll make sure I use it next time.  Do you have any ideas about the axis though?

Comment: I had a good look at this last night. I ran it and compared it to the blocks example. I just can't see why the yAxis on the left isn't moving.

Comment: Should there be a semi-colon at the end of     yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(1);    ? It should just be a comma.

Comment: perhaps you could mark the answer and let me know if it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling yAxis you need to add to the group the class y-axis not axis--y

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .zoom {
    cursor: move;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  circle {
    /*fill: #FF7700;*/
    fill: red;
    /*fill-opacity: 0.4;*/
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
  }

  .axis {
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke: #888;
    font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
  }

  .axis>path {
    stroke: #888;
  }
</style>

<body>
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

</script-->
<script>
  var data = [{
      "message_id": 1970268,
      "sent_time": "2013-04-05",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 2298946,
      "sent_time": "2013-05-29",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 2575515,
      "sent_time": "2013-07-13",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 2610242,
      "sent_time": "2013-07-17",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 2926234,
      "sent_time": "2013-08-20",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3110458,
      "sent_time": "2013-09-06",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 2
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3130002,
      "sent_time": "2013-09-08",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 3
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3255637,
      "sent_time": "2013-09-18",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 4
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3387239,
      "sent_time": "2013-09-29",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3447200,
      "sent_time": "2013-10-03",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 7
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3861761,
      "sent_time": "2013-11-05",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 7
    },
    {
      "message_id": 3949012,
      "sent_time": "2013-11-12",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4082149,
      "sent_time": "2013-11-21",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4155079,
      "sent_time": "2013-11-27",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4214299,
      "sent_time": "2013-12-03",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 4
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4348242,
      "sent_time": "2013-12-12",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 3
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4374202,
      "sent_time": "2013-12-15",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 6
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4384330,
      "sent_time": "2013-12-16",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 3
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4495880,
      "sent_time": "2013-12-26",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4569256,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-01",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 3
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4583204,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-02",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4621515,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-04",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 7
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4678673,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-07",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 1
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4743194,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-10",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 4
    },
    {
      "message_id": 4761212,
      "sent_time": "2014-01-11",
      "messages_sent_in_day": 5
    }
  ];
</script>
<script>
  /* Adapted from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 */

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 90,
      left: 50
    },
    margin2 = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 400
    },
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    width2 = 500 - margin2.left - margin2.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

  var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([5, width - 100]),
    x2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([5, width2]),
    y = d3.scaleTime().range([10, height]),
    y2 = d3.scaleTime().range([10, height]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisRight(y).tickSize(1),
    yAxis2 = d3.axisLeft(y2).tickSize(1);

  var brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width2, height]
    ])
    .on("brush", brushed);

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  // Data Load from CSV

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sent_time = parseTime(d.sent_time);
  });

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.messages_sent_in_day;
  });
  var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.messages_sent_in_day;
  });
  var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.sent_time;
  });
  var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.sent_time;
  });

  x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
  y.domain([yMin, new Date()]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  var num_messages = function(dataArray, domainRange) {
    return d3.sum(dataArray, function(d) {
      return d.sent_time >= domainRange.domain()[0] && d.sent_time <= domainRange.domain()[1];
    })
  }

  // append scatter plot to main chart area
  var messages = focus.append("g");
  messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  messages.selectAll("message")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'message')
    .attr("r", 2)
    .style("opacity", 0.4)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.messages_sent_in_day);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.sent_time);
    })

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    // .attr("class", "axis axis--y") //this was incorrect!!!
    .attr("class", "axis y-axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Summary Stats
  focus.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("x", 0 - height)
    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date..,.");

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left) / 2) + " ," +
      (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Messages");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

  // append scatter plot to brush chart area
  var messages = context.append("g");
  messages.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  messages.selectAll("message")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'messageContext')
    .attr("r", 1)
    .style("opacity", .6)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x2(d.messages_sent_in_day);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y2(d.sent_time);
    })

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis y-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ", 0)")
    .call(yAxis2);

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, y.range());



  //create brush function redraw scatterplot with selection
  function brushed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
    var s = d3.event.selection || y2.range();
    y.domain(s.map(y2.invert, y2));
    focus.selectAll(".message")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.messages_sent_in_day);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.sent_time);
      });
    focus.select(".y-axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(height / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(s[0], 0));
  }

  function zoomed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    y.domain(t.rescaleY(y2).domain());
    focus.selectAll(".message")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.messages_sent_in_day);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.sent_time);
      });
    focus.select(".y-axis").call(yAxis);
    context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, y.range().map(t.invertY, t));
  }
</script>
```